# WSO2 Basic Authentication returns error

Tags: authentication, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to use the authenticationendpoint application that comes with WSO2 as the new only login entry point of an old application. For testing purposes I just did a page that redirects to thi URL

https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do?relyingParty=My-Issuer&sp=Test-App&sessionDataKey=14792551&authenticators=BasicAuthenticator:LOCAL

The login page appears as expected, but once I set the user and password shows this message:

Authentication Error !
Attention:
Something went wrong during the authentication process. Please try signing in again.

Seeing the output in the console on debug mode, this is what is shown

... Many of the same error saying that Authentication Context is null
[2017-01-06 15:40:08,836] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils} -  Authentication Context is null
[2017-01-06 15:40:08,836] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils} -  Authentication Context is null
[2017-01-06 15:40:08,836] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils} -  Authentication Context is null
[2017-01-06 15:40:08,837] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Session data key  :  22451696
[2017-01-06 15:40:08,837] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache

I thing I'm doing something wrong, maybe there are not enough parameters sent, or they are the wrong ones, the user and password are correct because I can login into the carbon itself with it, and it is also a valid user for the testing SP.

The SP config is described:

**Basic Information**

Service Provider Name: Test-App

**Claim configuration**

Use Local Claim Dialect
Subject Claim URI http://wso2.org/claims/username

Role/Permission Configuration 
Permissions AdminTest
Role Mapping AdminTest->Admin

**Inbound Authentication Configuration**

- SAML2 Web SSO Configuration
  Issuer: My-Issuer

  Assertion Consumer URLs: https : //localhost/Test/main.asp
  Default Assertion Consumer URL: https : //localhost/Test/main.asp
  NameID format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
  Certificate alias: wso2carbon
  Response Signing Algorithm: ...#rsa-sha1
  Response Digest Algorithm: ...#sha1

Checked values
    Enable Response Signing
    Enable Single Logout
    Enable Attribute Profile
    Include Attributes in the Response Always
    Enable IdP Initiated SSO
    Enable IdP Initiated SLO

Others are in blank OAuth, OpenID, etc (let me know if that is maybe the problem, so which should be filled out.

**Local and Outbound Authentication Configuration**

Authentication Type: I tried with Default and Local Authentication = basic and password-reset-enforcer

This is checked:

- Assert identity using mapped local subject identifier
- Use tenant domain in local subject identifier
- Use user store domain in local subject identifier

  *Request Path Authentication Configuration*
  basic-auth

**Inbound Provisioning Configuration**
  *SCIM Configuration*
     PRIMARY
  Dumb Mode is not enabled

The rest is left blank

I have spent many days tracking this problem but no answers or are for older versions.

I tested with JDK 7 and 8 (latest of them) I'm working with WSO2 IS 5.2.0. Someone can lead me to a solution to use this application as the only entry point for my SPs? The idea after is to send back a SAML2 response to a page in the SP side that read the information and control the authorization part.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured for a SAML SSO scenario. Therefore your SP have to call the SAML SSO endpoint of WSO2 Identity Server with a valid SAMLRequest. That is https://hostname:port/samlsso.

AuthenticationEndpoint is just an **intermediary application**. SAML SSO endpoint is the one that should redirect the user to AuthenticationEndpoint *after first processing the SAMLRequest*. You must not call it directly.

Refer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Configuring+Single+Sign-On) to learn how to run a sample SAML SSO application with WSO2 IS. While running that, you can monitor the HTTP Request/Response flow using a tool like [SSOTracer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sso-tracer/) for Firefox and understand how the communication works.

In similar to SAML SSO flow, if you are using any other authentication protocol, you first have to call the protocol specific endpoint. E.g. If you are using OAuth2 or OpenIDConnect, then you should call /oauth2 endpoint. Never /authenticationendpoint directly.

Comment: Thanks drox. However following the indications on the page I hit a wall due to a pom.xml error, because it requires another non-existent pom.xml at is-samples directory level. do I need to clone the whole wso2 IS project?. I tried eliminating the parent xml entry, eliminating the relative path entry and eliminating the parent xml entry and adding the groupId and version as project element attribute, but the same problem. I'm not familiar with maven , but I tried with mvn alone, mvn clean install and mvn build and always the same issue

Comment: Sorry I hit enter before finish. I've tried eliminating the parent xml entry  in the pom.xml inside the samples directory, but it says that groupId is missing and version is missing, so I eliminated the relative path entry on samples pom file into the parent entry and now the error says that there is a non-resolvable parent POM.

Comment: Finally I eliminated the parent xml entry and adding the groupId and version as project element attributes (xsi:groupId="org.wso2.is" and tried also with "wso2is-identity-samples" as the artifact) in the pom file into samples directory, but the same problem with missed groupId and version. I'm not familiar with maven though, but I tried with mvn alone, mvn clean install and mvn build and always the same issue for those scenarios described. I also searched a pom at modules level in github, but there is none there (and it was updated to v5.3.0 today, but no pom either into modules directory).